# fabric:Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing

Tags: python, local, fabric

errors below

```
>>> local("cat /tmp/11|grep '23'")
[localhost] local: cat /tmp/11|grep '23'
l100.cpu.total,2016-11-30 10:39:00,23.0

>>> local("cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12'")
[localhost] local: cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12'

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12''
```

Aborting.

in os returns ok

(flask)[root@vq22flk01 ~]# cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12'

Answer (score 0):

Your error message:

```
Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12''
```

Don't use '' multiple times.

Instead, You can write like this : "cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12' "

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I do use "cat /tmp/11|grep '23:12' " but it returns same error